# Reading Values from Known file located on system

Tags: json, uwp, template10, filepicker

I'm new to Stack Overflow, otherwise I would have commented to the primary question in this post...

[UWP apps accessing files from random location on system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692686/uwp-apps-accessing-files-from-random-location-on-system)

My situation is similar, but different. It seems that in the post above, that they are trying to read values from a file selected by the user via file picker.

Where I differ is I would like to read a file created my SCCM team, stored on every computer within company. This file will have values like HD Serial Number and Windows Creation date. (values that I can not easily read without doing something like Windows Brokered Component). [[Good article here if anyone interested](https://xamltips.wordpress.com/2016/01/07/brokered-component-starter-kit-for-uwp-app/)]

Since I know the path of file ahead of time, I'm hoping I can just do like so...
*(not on my VS2015 pc, pardon my hacked logic... Hopefully my answers will magically come back in Cut&Paste code ;-))*

```
if 
    file exist within %localappdata%\MyAppName\ImportedValues.JSON
else
    Open FilePicker (location of PowerShellScript that will rerun creation of JSON file)
```

JSON File Sample

```
{  
    "Hardware": {  
        "TerminalID": "NameOfThisComputer",  
        "HardDriveSN": "111111111",  
        "HardDriveModel": "SamsungSSD",  
        "StagingStartDate": "Thursday, September 17, 2009 3:58:54 PM"  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your UWP app doenst have access to read any file on the computer. SO they have to place it in the appdata folder as you can find here: http://caioproiete.net/en/physical-location-of-windows-store-applications-and-data-on-a-pc/

or it need to be opened via filepicker.

Comment: So I would have to install the app first, then have JSON file populated with Values, and added to %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\{PackageId}\LocalState later..   Then I could just change my IF references inside of application to ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder\ImportedValues.JSON?

Comment: that would be correct there is a whole bunch of folders there you could even do it in the Roaming folder...